# JSONArray em JSONObject: erro Json.typeMistach

Tags: java, json

Em uma pesquisada pela web descobri que o erro Json.typeMistach era devido a eu esta recebendo um `JSONArray` e tentando seta-lo em um `JSONObject`.

Acontece que não consigo consertar, o erro persiste.

Alguém poderia me dar uma mão ou me indicar um tutorial para o problema?

**Meu JSON**:

```
[
   {
      "id":19761,
      "nome_oficina":"Oficina Beira Mar"
   },
   {
      "id":19838,
      "nome_oficina":"Oficina Beira Mar"
   },
   {
      "id":19948,
      "nome_oficina":"Oficina Beira Mar"
   }
]
```

**Meu código para converter o JSONArray em JSONObject**:

```
private void parseJson(String data) {

    String strJson=data;

    try {
    JSONObject jsnJsonObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
    JSONArray contacts = jsnJsonObject.getJSONArray("NAO SEI O QUE POR AQUI, JÁ QUE MINHA STRING NÃO SE INICIA COM TIPO DO OBJETO");

        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++)
        {       
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = c.getString("id");
            String boy_code = c.getString("nome_oficina");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Você recebe um `JSONArray`, só precisa percorrê-lo acessando cada índice (que é um `JSONObject`):

```
private static void parseJson(String data){    
    try {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data);

        // Percorrendo cada índice
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){

            // Obtendo o objeto do índice atual
            JSONObject json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            String id = json.get("id").toString();
            String boy_code = json.get("nome_oficina").toString();                
            System.out.println("id: " + id + " - boy_code: " + boy_code);
        }       
    } catch(JSONException err){
        // Tratamento de exceções
    }
}
```

#### output:

> id: 19761 - boy_code: Oficina Beira Mar
>   id: 19838 - boy_code: Oficina Beira Mar
>   id: 19948 - boy_code: Oficina Beira Mar

Comment: Muito obrigado re22.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução parecida com a do r22 que eu havia encontrado. Apenas para galera poder usar de base no entendimento também.

```
    try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(SetServerString);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); ++i) {
                JSONObject rec = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                int id = rec.getInt("id");
               Log.i("__PRINT__",String.valueOf(id));

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```